# run method for each groupby list (or array)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a folder that has pictures for specific "policies." Each policy may contain any number of pictures. The folder could also contain any number of policies.

VAH007157100-pic1.jpg
VAH007157100-pic2.jpg
VAH007157100-pic3.jpg

WAZ009999200-pic1.jpg
WAZ009999200-pic2.jpg
WAZ009999200-pic3.jpg
WAZ009999200-pic4.jpg
...

Foreach policy GROUP, I want to run a method (CreateTiffFile()) that takes in an ARRAY (of files in this group) and performs certain actions.

In the example above, the method would run twice (because there are 2 distinct policies). I would also have 2 distinct arrays. One array containing VAH007157100 pictures (3 in this case) and another array (WAZ009999200) containing 4 pictures.

How would I run this method on each group array?

let me know if i wasn't clear enough. remember, the number of policies and the number of pictures per policy varies so i need to take that into account.

For a better vision (based on data above):

```
CreateTiffFile(array containing VAH007157100 pics);
CreateTiffFile(array containing WAZ009999200 pics);
```

...

and so on.

Comment: Can you show us the existing LINQ statement?

Comment: i updated the question. that's what im trying to figure out how to construct. im not sure :(

Comment: So your question is actually how to group these files?

Comment: well basically I need to group them, then for each group, create an array for it (containing the group members) which I will pass to the "CreateTiffFile(array)" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> grouped = theFiles.GroupBy(filename => filename.Split('-')[0])).Select(g => g.ToArray());

foreach(var group in grouped)
    CreateTiffFile(group);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list (be it an array or some other collection) of strings named `files`:

```
var groups = files.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('-')));
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    CreateTiffFile(group.ToArray()); // ToArray() returns a string[] with the file names
}
```

Comment: trying this now. ps. I think you meant to say group.toArray(); not groupS :)

Comment: kendall, unfortunately the code you have doesn't split the groups into arrays for me to use each. Reed got it right. thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm sorry if I missed something. I think mine does exactly the same thing as Reed's. Can you tell me what didn't work?

Comment: the group by only gave me data for the first group. it didn't really separate the groups (in this case 2). only gave me one...

Comment: Oh, I see the mistake now. I'll update. Sorry for being so blind.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is close to this:

```
// get the filenames somehow
string[] filenames = ...;

// split the filenames
char[] breaker = new char[]{ '-' };
var policies_and_numbers = filenames.Select(fname => fname.Split(breaker));
// item is an string[]: [0] is policy, [1] is filename

// group them by the policy
var grouped = policies_and_numbers.GroupBy(thearr => thearr[0]);

// ensure the grouped items are kept as arrays
var almostdone = grouped.Select(group => new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>(group.Key, group.ToArray());
// now, the item is KVP, key is the Policy, and the Value is the array of pics

foreach(var pair in almostdone)
    CreateTiffFile(pair.Key, pair.Value); // first arg = policyname, second = the array of "pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg"...
```

edit: the code has been bloated for clarity of actions. You can easily compress it to a one-liner like the other posters have shown :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string CalcGroup(string filename) { ... }
string CreateTiffFile(IEnumerable<string> filesInGroup) { ... }
//...
files.GroupBy(CalcGroup).ToList().ForEach(CreateTiffFile);
```